# Simple TabBar on a View for 2 Other views?

Tags: iphone, ios, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

I wanna have a SettingViewMain with a TabBar, which can Flip between SettingView1 and SettingView2.

I tried this simple work since 3 hours and try nearly all tutorials I found, but I don't get it to work.

When I try to add a TabBar programmatically, I can flip between this 2 views, but in this views itself the TabBar is not shown, don't know why. When I add a TabBarController, this is not shown at all.

So, simlpy: How do I add a TabBar on a MasterView (not a AppDelegate-Window or something like this) and get the TabBar to switch between View1 and View2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate a UITabBarController using its alloc and init methods.
Instantiate both other ViewControllers and add them to an array.
After doing so, add it's view to your 'MasterView'.

Code:

```
UITabBarController *tab = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
UIViewController *controller1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *controller2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

NSArray *controllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:controller1, controller2, nil];   
[tab setViewControllers:controllers];

[[self view] addSubview:[tab view]];
```

Or something closely compared to this.

Good luck!

Bryan